# ALOS PALSAR resampling

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, landsat, resampling

I want to combine Landsat bands with the backscatter coefficients of ALOS PALSAR. I used the following code to resample and combine. However, the HH, HV bands in combine image showed with 'masked'. I did Lee filter and converted DB to backscatter coefficient for ALOS PALSAR. The result seems no problem. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
//Resampling
var landsatProjection = imageC.first().select('B2').projection();
print('landsatProjection:', landsatProjection);

HH_HV_2017 = HH_HV_2017
    .reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels: 1024
    })
    .reproject({
      crs: landsatProjection
    });

var HH = HH_HV_2017.select("HH")
var HV = HH_HV_2017.select("HV")
var Def = HH_HV_2017.select("Def")

var newproj = HH.projection().getInfo()
print (newproj)

var image_combined = image_selected.addBands(HH).addBands(HV).addBands(Def)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using GEE? If so, please add that to your tag. Also, you mentioned that the results seem fine, but you ask what is wrong with your code--could you please clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Thank you for yr response. The results for Lee filter and DB conversion seems to be fine. But the result for resampling is not correct. That's my problem.